# Javascript not working after jQuery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm creating a dynamically content from an API using jQuery ajax function.

My code is below

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  url : "api_url",
  type: "POST",
  dataType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data : JSON.stringify(myData),
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
   result_data = JSON.parse(data);
   
   console.log("result data: ");
   console.log(result_data);
   console.log(textStatus);
   console.log("Data : ");
   console.log(data);
   console.log(jqXHR);
   
   
   jQuery('.booking-list').append('<li><a class="booking-item" href="#"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="booking-item-car-img"><img src="img/insurance-companies/interlife.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Image Title"/><p class="booking-item-car-title">Σύνολο Καλύψεων : 1</p></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><ul class="booking-item-features booking-item-features-small clearfix"><li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Αστική Ευθύνη Έναντι Τρίτων"><i class="fa fa-male"></i><span class="booking-item-feature-sign"></span></li><li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Θραύση κρυστάλλων σε Α κίνδυνο έως 1.000€"><i class="im im-car-window"></i><span class="booking-item-feature-sign"></span></li><li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Οδική Βοήθεια"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i><span class="booking-item-feature-sign"></span></li></ul></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="checkbox"><label><input class="i-check" type="checkbox"/>Οδική Βοήθεια</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input class="i-check" type="checkbox"/>Θραύση Κρυστάλλων</label></div></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><span class="booking-item-price">&euro;51,02</span><span></span><p class="booking-item-flight-class">Basic Simple</p><span class="btn btn-primary">Αγορά</span></div></div></a></li>');
   
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
   console.log(jqXHR);
   console.log(textStatus);
   console.log(errorThrown);
   
   jQuery('.booking-list').append('<li><a class="booking-item" href="#"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="booking-item-car-img"><img src="img/insurance-companies/interlife.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Image Title"/><p class="booking-item-car-title">Σύνολο Καλύψεων : 1</p></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><ul class="booking-item-features booking-item-features-small clearfix"><li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Αστική Ευθύνη Έναντι Τρίτων"><i class="fa fa-male"></i><span class="booking-item-feature-sign"></span></li><li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Θραύση κρυστάλλων σε Α κίνδυνο έως 1.000€"><i class="im im-car-window"></i><span class="booking-item-feature-sign"></span></li><li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Οδική Βοήθεια"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i><span class="booking-item-feature-sign"></span></li></ul></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="checkbox"><label><input class="i-check" type="checkbox"/>Οδική Βοήθεια</label></div><div class="checkbox"><label><input class="i-check" type="checkbox"/>Θραύση Κρυστάλλων</label></div></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><span class="booking-item-price">&euro;51,02</span><span></span><p class="booking-item-flight-class">Basic Simple</p><span class="btn btn-primary">Αγορά</span></div></div></a></li>');
  }
 });
```

The problem is that after success occurs the html classes arent take effect.

[image]

The first item on the picture is before ajax request (manual written on html code) and the second is an .append after ajax success.

The checkbox on the second item hasnt the class' styling and effects.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you using a specific libraries (CSS/JS) to stylish your checkbox ? 
Maybe you need to reset/relaunch the javascript function that stylish your checkboxes.
because the dom is updated but the onDomReady event is not applied again after a dom modification/insertion.

Comment: Yes, I'm using specific libraries. But I cannot understand why arent working. 

I have load all the files before the closing body tag. When I reload the page, the first part works fine. The API gives a callback in about 3-4 seconds and when I render the data with .append the libraries dont work.

How can I relaunce those libraries?

Comment: What is the library you are using to enhance the checkbox ? Like to create "fake" checkbox . Is that something that enhance as well the input, the select? If you could just share this, I can help you out !

Answer (score 0):

What you want to append after success should already be in your HTML template. Use `display: none` CSS property and jQuery `hide()` and `show()` functions.

It may solve your problem. Even if it does not you should do it anyway : it's easier to read and easier to maintain.

Comment: The reason that I have the first part on the HTML page is only for displaying purposes. I want to get data from this request and after that append them to a specific div.